# LCD on Canon Rebel T2i stopped working after tethering to Mac

Tags: canon, lcd

After plugging my camera in to my MacBook Pro and using it successfully in live mode, an error message popped up on my computer saying "USB device is draining too much power. USB device has been disabled. " My EOS crashed and the LCD on my camera went dark. No matter what I do, I can't get the LCD screen to turn back on.  Everything else seems to be in working order. Is there a way I can fix this? It's $300 for Canon to replace the LCD screen and I just spent $300 on a new lens, I don't really want to spend that much on replacing a part, and I don't want to have to spend $600 on a new camera.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the LCD, it is the driver card of the LCD that burnt out (more specifically, the power regulator that went hopefully into current limiting or shut off). This should be repaired under warranty by Canon... You must not be able to pull currents from any source without the internal regulators limiting it. (Except, if you plugged your camera into a USB 3.1 12 V or 20 V port, I highly doubt it.)

So get the problem fixed by Canon. If they do not fix it, get the problem assessed by a technician, who might as well just do a quick rework on the burnt out part. (Or get a replacement component on Alibaba...)